# Capillary action strength questions

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water, capillary-action

I've been studying capillary action, and I've drawn some conclusions about the behavior which surprised me, and I want to know if I'm understanding it correctly.

According to Jurin's law, the height of liquid in a capillary tube is inversely proportional to the radius, so assuming all other variables are constant, height = 1/r.

As r increases and the column becomes wider, the water height goes down. However, if you calculate the volume of water: $$Height\times \pi\times r^2 = 1/r \times \pi\times r^2 =\pi\times r$$, it shows that the overall volume if water in the column is increasing linearly with r. So capillary action is actually getting stronger (in a way) as the tube becomes larger. This makes intuitive sense, as the surface area of the tube is increasing, so there is more surface to pull on the water.

Going further. The center of mass of the column of water will be half way up the height, so height/2. Using the volume of the water as it's mass, then the potential energy of the raised volume of water will be weight * height/2 = (pi * r) * (1/2r) = pi/2. So the actual potential energy of the mass of water going up the column is **constant** as the radius changes.

So, as a function of the radius:

1. The **height** of the water column **decreases** linearly as r increases.
2. The **volume** of the water column **increases** linearly as r increases, meaning that the upward force exerted by the tube on the water against gravity increases linearly.
3. The total potential energy of the raised volume of water is **constant**, regardless of the radius of the tube.

Is this all correct? Or am I making some mistakes somewhere?